# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.data"

Tags: android, android-databinding

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/a"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.a.AFragment">
    <data>
        <import type="android.databinding.ObservableArrayMap"/>
        <variable name="user" type="ObservableArrayMap"/>
    </data>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{user.name}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I get the following error on running:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class data
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class data
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.data" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/x.x.x-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/x.x.x-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/x.x.x-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/x.x.x-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/x.x.x-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/x.x.x-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/x.x.x-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/x.x.x-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/x.x.x-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/x.x.x-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/x.x.x-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/x.x.x-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/x.x.x-2/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

The error is on the `<data>` line (begin tag).

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: add <layout> tag as root of your xml .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Data binding layout files are slightly different and start with a root tag of `layout` followed by a `data` element and a view root element

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions

You don't have a generic layout tag

Comment: After fixing my original code, I get this error:
> Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:text' with parameter type V on android.widget.TextView
This is for `android:text="@{user.name}"`

Comment: @battery You can manage to solve it by deleting .idea, .gradle and `gradle` folders and let Android Studio recreate the whole project from scratch from `gradle `files.

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha How would that help? Is this documented in any way somewhere?

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha I think you mean, "Is your problem solved?" And no, your suggestion has resulted in another error.

Comment: @battery From the docs, `type="com.example.User"`... Not sure why you have this "ObserableArrayMap" thing

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, for my user field I did not create a separate User type, I'm just using the ObservableArrayMap instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [sample layout](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions) file. Modify your layout accordingly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <data>
       <variable name="user" type="com.example.User"/>
   </data>
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@{user.firstName}"/>
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@{user.lastName}"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following the things for the dataBinding in Android

First make sure , you are adding the `dataBinding`inside your **build.gradle** for the model.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "YOUR_APPP"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true   //// This is need to be for the dataBinding
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}
```

The second one inside your the **build.gradle** (Project) need to use the `jcenter()` entry inside the `repositories`

```
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
      delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

And the last one inside the **layout.xml** , you need to `start` and `end` tag using the **`layout`** tag like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/splash"
        tools:context=".user.activity.SplashActivity">


         /**
          * USE YOUR ALL RESOURCES HERE
          */

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

For more understanding refer this site [Reference site](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions)